# How can i change the values in a dictionary that are inside another dictionary?

Tags: vb.net, dictionary, multidimensional-array

I've come here after hours of looking on the internet. Nothing comes close to what I am trying to achieve.

I have this:-

```
Private Portfolio_Client_List As New Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, Double))
```

which I then add keys to like the following:-

```
Portfolio_Client_List.Add(str.Substring(6, 5).Trim, New Dictionary(Of String, Double))
```

then I add keys to the other dictionary like the below:-

```
For Each pair As KeyValuePair(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, Double)) In Portfolio_Client_List
    pair.Value.Add("Office Collections", 0.00)
    pair.Value.Add("Home Collections", 0.00)
Next
```

Now I want to update the values in the `Office Collections` and `Home Collections` keys values.

How can I do so? I thought it would be as simple as:-

```
For Each pair As KeyValuePair(Of String, Double) In Portfolio_Client_List("key")
    pair.Value += Head_Office_Payments
Next
```

However it just gives me the readonly error. Is there any way to do this, or am I wasting my time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, [`KeyValuePairs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42(v=vs.110).aspx) are immutable structs, so you can't modify them, [`Value`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224761(v=vs.110).aspx) is readonly.

But this works (you want to add `Head_Office_Payments` to the old value):

```
Dim dict As Dictionary(Of String, Double) = Portfolio_Client_List("key")
For Each key As String In dict.Keys.ToList()
    dict(key) += Head_Office_Payments
Next
```

Note that you need the `dict.Keys.ToList`(creates a new list) because you can't modify the collection while enumerating, setting the `Value` of a dictionary increases it's version number which invalidates the iterator. That's why i prefer this one-liner LINQ solution:

```
dict = dict.ToDictionary(Function(kv) kv.Key, Function(kv) kv.Value + Head_Office_Payments)
```

Comment: Darn, was just about to post my answer. You were only a couple of seconds too fast ;). Just keep in mind that the OP appears to _add_ `Head_Office_Payments` to the previous value.

Comment: @VisualVincent: yes, fixed and added another approach